# Update element in static vue component when sibling component changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

This is my first time asking a question so I'm hoping I get this right.

I have a project where my App.vue template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <appheader></appheader>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <appfooter></appfooter>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in my `<appheader>` component i have a login button that redirects to the login page:

```
<router-link tag="div" to="/login">
   <a>
     <div class="signInButton">
       <div class="lockWrapper">
         <img class="lock" src="../assets/lock.svg" alt="">
       </div>
       <h4 class="loginText">Log in</h4>
     </div>
   </a>
</router-link>
```

What I want is for the button to show "Log out" when the user is logged in.
When the user logs in they get a cookie that i use to verify in components if a user has logged in or not, but since the `<appheader>` isn't reloaded, the value doesn't change unless I refresh the page. Is there a way to update the header whenever a new component is being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around by using `this.$root.$emit('event', data)` in one component and picking up the event with `this.$root.$on('event', (data) => {})`.

This seemed to update the header component without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use Vuex to store your state.
for more info: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)